# Is $\{g(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\in\ell_2$ if $g$ is a Sobolev function on the real line?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If we are given a function $g\in W_2^k(\mathbb{R})$ (even consider $k=1$ for simplicity), then is it true or not that $\{g(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\in\ell_2$?  That is, do we have $$\underset{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum|g(n)|^2<\infty$$
?

At first I thought that this must be false, but after trying for a while to construct a counterexample, I found it a little more difficult than I thought.  The conclusion is certainly not true for functions only in $L_2(\mathbb{R})=W_2^0(\mathbb{R})$, because consider the function $g$ so that $g^2$ forms triangles or tent functions at each integer of height 1 and width $2^{-n}$.  The area is square summable, but the above sum is infinite.  However when we have to have control over even the first derivative it becomes a little harder, because such a tent function no longer works.

My idea was to try to set $g(n)=n^{-1/2}$ for an infinite subset of the natural numbers (consider $g(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$), and try to ensure that the functions derivative was small enough to be square summable, but this didn't seem to work.

Any suggestions or comments would be helpful.  I am sure somebody knows this even though I have never seen it before.

Comment: Hint: consider the periodization of $g$ by $G(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} g(x+n)$. What can we say about $G$ as a function on the unit interval? Which spaces does it lie in?

Comment: Could you clarify your hint a little? I understand than the $L_2$ norm of $g$ is equal to $\int_0^1 \sum_n |g(x+n)|^2 dx$, but I am not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: Sorry just needed one more step. It would seem we have $\sum_n |g(n)|^2\leq \sum_n\int_0^1|g(x+n)|^2dx=\|g\|_{L_2}$?

Comment: No, it's just that you can show that $G$ is in $W^1_2([0,1])$, whence you can use the Morrey-Sobolev embedding to see that it must be a continuous function, and hence bounded.

Comment: Oops. I realize this doesn't help that much, because you wanted $\sum |g(n)|^2$. I will keep thinking about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem**

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be a set of separated points in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\underset{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\inf x_{n+1}-x_n>c$.
If $g\in W_p^k(\mathbb{R})$, $1\leq p\leq\infty$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $(g(x_n))\in\ell_p$.

**Proof:**

First, in the $p=\infty$ case, if $g\in W_\infty^k(\mathbb{R})$, then $g$ is Lipschitz, and so the result is obvious. (That $W_\infty^1(\mathbb{R})=Lip(\mathbb{R})$ is a nontrivial result).

So we tackle the case $1\leq p<\infty$.  Let $$I_n:=\left[x_n-\frac{c}{3},x_n+\frac{c}{3}\right],\quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$
We define them this way so that they are disjoint, and also $|I_n|=\frac{2}{3}c$ for all $n$. By disjointness, we have that
$$\underset{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum\int_{I_n}|g|^p\leq\int_\mathbb{R}|g|^p<\infty$$
On the other hand, if $y_n:=\underset{x\in I_n}{argmin}|g(x)|^p$, then we have that
$$|g(y_n)|^p\frac{2}{3}c\leq\int_{I_n}|g|^p$$
and consequently, $(g(y_n))\in\ell_p$.

The following Lemma will be very useful presently.

**Lemma:** [*A First Course in Sobolev Spaces*, Leoni, Thm 7.13, p.222]

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ be open and $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$.  Let $1\leq p<\infty$.  Then $u\in W_p^1(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if it admits an absolutely continuous representative, $\tilde{u}:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\tilde{u}$ and its classical derivative $\tilde{u}'$ belong to $L_p(\mathbb{R})$.  Moreover, if $p>1$, then $\tilde{u}$ is Holder continuous of exponent $1/p'$.

So since $W_p^k(\mathbb{R})\subset W_p^1(\mathbb{R})$, taking $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ in the Lemma allows us without loss of generality to assume that $g$ is absolutely continuous.  Therefore by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, 
$$g(x_n)=g(y_n)+\int_{y_n}^{x_n}g(t)dt$$
Using the inequality $|a+b|^p\leq 2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p)$, we have
$$|g(x_n)|^p\leq 2^p\left[|g(y_n)|^p+\left|\int_{y_n}^{x_n}g(t)dt\right|^p\right]\leq 2^p\left[|g(y_n)|^p+\left(\frac{2c}{3}\right)^\frac{p}{p'}\int_{I_n}|g(t)|^pdt\right]$$
The second inequality follows by Holder's Inequality:
$$\left|\int_{y_n}^{x_n}g(t)dt\right|^p\leq\left(\int_{y_n}^{x_n}|g(t)|dt\right)^p\leq |I_n|^\frac{p}{p'}\int_{I_n}|g(t)|^pdt$$

We conclude that
$$\underset{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum|g(x_n)|^p\leq C\left[\underset{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum|g(y_n)|^p+\underset{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum\int_{I_n}|g|^p\right]<\infty$$
and the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! This is actually a bit of a tricksy problem in Fourier analysis. What you want to do is, consider the Fourier transform of $g$, call it $\hat{g}$. Since $g$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, so is $\hat{g}$, by the properties of the Fourier transform.

Now let's periodize $\hat{g}$ into a  function we will suggestively call $\hat{G}$ with
$$ \hat{G} (k) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{g}(m+k)$$
Then $\hat{G}$ is a periodic function on the unit interval, so it has a Fourier series representation. What are the Fourier coefficients of $\hat{G}$?

The Poisson summation formula tells us that they are precisely the values of our original function! To be precise, 
$$\hat{G}(k) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} g(n) e^{-2\pi i n k}$$
From here, it should be clear that 
$$ \sum_n |g(n)|^2 = \|\hat{G}\|_{L^2([0,1])}^2 = \|g\|^2_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$$

(Response to comment): gerw, you've put your finger on precisely the interesting point of this problem that I neglected in my original answer. My apologies for neglecting it.

To use the Fourier transform as I have, you need the Poisson summation formulation to be valid, in the sense that $\hat{g}$ needs to be integrable (see, e.g., Stein and Weiss, Chapter VII, Theorem 2.3). This is, to say the least, not true of general $L^2$ functions $g$, but for Sobolev functions it follows from 
$$ \int |\hat{g}(k)| dk \leq \int |\hat{g}(k) (1+|k|^2)^\frac{1}{2}| \frac{1}{(1+|k|^2)^\frac{1}{2}} dk \leq \left(\int |\hat{g}(k)|^2 (1 + |k|^2) dk \right)^\frac{1}{2} \left (\int \frac{1}{1+|k|^2} dk \right)^\frac{1}{2} $$
The first term in the final expression is well known to be the $W^1_2$ norm of $g$, and the second is integrable and a constant.

Comment: Where do you used $g \in W_2^1(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: That is a good comment, because IF this is true the proof must use in a crucial way that the derivative is in $L_2$ because if $g$ is even continuous and only in $L_2$ not sobolev then the conclusion fails.

Comment: There was a counter example construction posted earlier but he claimed that the derivative was square integrable and I was not so sure based on the construction.

Comment: @gerw I have, I hope, answered your query. That was a good point, because in general the Poisson summation formula doesn't hold.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I finally went through all of it to check.  Forgetting the simple fact that lead to your conclusion that $\sum|g(n)|^2=\|\widehat{G}\|_2^2$ cost me no small amount of time, but I managed to dig into the recesses of my Fourier analysis knowledge to remember the easy $L_2$ theory finally.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but what ensures that $\widehat{G}$ is in $L_2[0,1]$?  It is certainly in $L_1[0,1]$, but when I try to calculate its 2-norm, I can't seem to find a good inequality.  By definition, $\int_0^1|\widehat{G}(x)|^2dx=\int_0^1\left|\sum_n\widehat{g}(x+n)\right|^2dx$.  But I don't necessarily see how to bound this by something useful after some effort.

Comment: Don't mean to ignore you, but things are a bit crazy at the end of the semester over here. I'll look into this in a day or two?

Comment: No worries I'm in the same boat. Ill post a solution if I figure it out in the meantime.

Comment: I found a proof to this and my more general question that is actually not fourier analytic. Ill post in a day or two when I get the chance.